# Entende de Cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

eu estava buscando mais conhecimento sobre cookies no youtube e só achei vídeo em Inglês, mas o que isso tem de mais? Eu não falo inglês! Contudo deu para eu entender que cookies funcionam desta forma → sã armazenados, lidos e algumas vez excluídos.

Onde quero chegar? 
Bem... Eu quero colocar cookies em 2 scripts, mas até agora não conseguir.
Eu tinha perguntado aqui no fórum como colocar cookies neste script↓↓↓

```js
<a id="id1" href="https://br.answers.yahoo.com" onclick="myFunction(event)" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a> <br/><br/>

<script language="javascript">
    function myFunction(s) {
        var id = s.target.id;

        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById(id).style.color = "blue";
        }, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

Então eu recebi essa resposta:↓

Se você quer que ela continue indefinidamente até que você a exclua, você pode fazer isto com html5, ou se você quer que esqueça os dados ao fechar o navegador também.

```js
INDEFINIDAMENTE: // Armazenar

localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Receber

var lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
// Remover

localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
TEMPORARIAMENTE // Armazenar

sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Receber

var lastname = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
// Remover

sessionStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```

Mas não entendi como inserir, tem como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript Cookie

Existe uma api bem detalhada para se trabalhar com Cookies através do JavaScript, de forma facil e e bem documentada.

Segue: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

#### Import:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>`

#### Gets and Set Cookies:

*Criar um cookie que expira 7 dias a partir de agora, válido em todo o site:*

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

*Ler o Cookie:*

```
Cookies.get('name');
```

*Ler todos os cookies visíveis*

```
Cookies.get();
```

*Delete cookie:*

```
Cookies.remove('name');
```

Na documentação do `github` há mais exemplos detalhados.

Comment: Valeu cara vou procurar entender mais

Comment: @Marcio.sx Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Em parte sim, porque no inicio eu queria pronto, mas foi melhor porque aprendi!

Comment: @Marcio.sx Se algumas das respostar resolveu o seu problema, seria interessante aceitar uma delas.

Comment: como faço isso?

Comment: @Marcio.sx Em baixo da numeração dos votos, aparece um "vezinho". Ali você pode clicar e aceitar uma das respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Não percebi bem que valores quer armazenar em cookies. Mas aqui estão uma funções que dão jeito para trabalhar com cookies do lado cliente:

Ativar cookie:

```
// entra como argumentos: o nome que quer dar ao cookie, respetivo valor, e número de dias para ficar ativo
function set_cookie(nome, valor, dias) {

    //data em que o cookie vai expirar, ficar desativo
    expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(dias) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    // set cookie
    document.cookie = name+'='+value+'; expires=' +expires+ '; path=/';

}
```

Verificar se existe:

```
// aqui entra o nome do cookie que quer e respetivo valor, vai-lhe ser returnado true (existe, já está ativo) ou false (não existe)
function cookie_exists(nome,valor) {

    var cookie = document.cookie; // Aqui vamos buscar todos os cookies do nosso site

    var cookieNameValue = cookie.split(";"); // vamos dividir a string por ';', para obtermos um array (vetor) com todos os nome/valores dos cookies
    var countCookies = cookieNameValue.length;
    var cookieWeWant = nome+"="+valor; // este é o cookie que queremos

    for(var i=0; i<countCookies; i++) {
        if(cookieWeWant == cookieNameValue[i].trim()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Apagar um cookie:

```
// aqui entra o nome do cookie que quer apagar
function delete_cookie(nome) {
    //para apagar um cookie basta ativar um cookie para uma data passada
    expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1);
    document.cookie = nome+'=123; expires=' +expires+ '; path=/';
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara, Ta bem detalhado! :-)